# How to execute processes in synchronization?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I'm creating a programm that goes through a system  directory and changes the file extension of each file in the directory. It works perfectly,however python searches through for the whole directory then it changes the files extension,this method takes a long time,so I tried to run both processes in syncro using the multiprocess library.Somehow it doesn't work plus it doesnt show any errors so I dont know what am doing wrong. Can anyone help me solve it?
Thanks

**CODE:**

```
import os
from multiprocessing import Process

c_phpfiles=[]
def walk():
    for dirpath,dirs,files in os.walk("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Newfolder"):
        for filename in files:
            fname = os.path.join(dirpath,filename)
            c_phpfiles.append(fname)

def change(files):
    for name in files:
        print name
        with open(name, 'wb') as fo:
            fo.write('this is a test')
        os.rename(name,name+'.test')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Process(target=walk)
    p1 = Process(target=change, args=(c_phpfiles,))
    p.start()
    p1.start()
    p.join()
    p1.join()
```

Comment: I'm not clear how this is supposed to work. `c_phpfiles` is an empty list at the point of calling `change`; how are the processes supposed to communicate data in an accumulating list?

Comment: I called the function walk() first, which will populate the list with name of the files then I called the function change() that it will take each file name contained inside the list then it will change the extension.                                     But it doesn't work @roganjosh

Comment: Then I'm confused over your objective. What exactly is supposed to be running at the same time?

Comment: it supposed to run both function at the same time. The second function should not not wait for the first function to scan the whole directory.it should change the file extension as the scan goes a long @roganjosh

Comment: Well then we've gone back to my initial comment. The contents of `c_phpfiles` are dynamic whilst `change` is supposed to be running. I guess you'd need to have a shared list between the two processes but I'm not sure how `change` is supposed to process the contents of that list.

Comment: inside the paramater files (change(files)) the list c_phpfiles will be inputted.then with a for loop it change each file extension @roganjosh

Comment: Actually, you can use a [`Queue()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes) and have `change` consume entries in the queue. Currently, `change` gets its own copy of `c_phpfiles` so it always sees an empty list. You need to look at interprocess communication or some kind of shared data structure.

Answer (score 0):

Create a list of files in the directory (tree).

Write a function that takes a file path as an argument and renames it.

Create a `multiprocessing.Pool`, and use its `map` method to apply the function to the list.